# pd.dataframe: problem formatting totals row with blank cells

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Relatively new to pandas, and I'm trying to do something that I think should be simple, but it's becoming very complex.  Either I'm doing it wrong or I've underestimated pandas.

I'm trying to add a single 'Totals' row to a dataframe, totalling one column only and ignoring the others, and have it display without NaN's, with numbers correctly formatted.  The prevailing advice seems to be to replace NaN with a blank string `df.fillna("")`, but that breaks normal number formatting for that column

I create a simple table, and append a row with the total of the only column I'm interested in:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 2.22,3.33],['B', 4.44, 5.55],['C',6.66,7.77]], columns=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
total_row = pd.DataFrame([['Total',df['baz'].sum()]], columns=['foo', 'baz'])
df = df.append(total_row, ignore_index=True)
```

```
>>> df
     foo   bar    baz
0      A  2.22   3.33
1      B  4.44   5.55
2      C  6.66   7.77
3  Total   NaN  16.65
```

...I now have a total row with the correct total.  Replace the NaN with a blank string:

```
df.replace(np.nan, "")
     foo   bar    baz
0      A  2.22   3.33
1      B  4.44   5.55
2      C  6.66   7.77
3  Total        16.65
```

Then format just the 'bar' column to 1DP

```
format_dict = {
    'bar':             "{:,.1f}"
}
styled_df = df.style.format(format_dict)
styled_df.render()
...
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

style.format understandably complains about trying to format a string to 1 decimal place.  I've solved this by writing a custom formatter for 'bar' that ignores strings:

```
format_dict = {
    'bar': lambda x: x if type(x) == str else f"${x:,.2f}"
}
```

This seems unnecessarily complicated for what I would have thought was a common use case.  Is there a simpler way of creating that totals row or formatting the table?

Expected result:

```
     foo   bar    baz
0      A  2.2    3.33
1      B  4.4    5.55
2      C  6.6    7.77
3  Total        16.65
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioned bar column in columns list i.e

```
pd.DataFrame([['Total', df['baz'].sum()]], columns=['foo', 'baz']),
```

in **bar** it will add NaN to short this just do this

```
pd.DataFrame([['Total','',df['baz'].sum()]], columns=['foo','bar', 'baz']).
```

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2poEk.png)

Comment: That's a slightly faster way of getting an empty string into ['Total']['bar'], at the expense of having to specify every df,column in the total_row definition.  But it still has the same problem of breaking the formatting for the bar column.